# Angularjs set static variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

To learn angularjs,I got demo from interent and want to set some static value of given login,password and other fields.

I have tried to make it working using google.But somehow its not working.
So will you suggest some ideas or help ?

It must need to work like
username value will be set into form fields name,email,login and password.
Once value has been set then submit from but its not working for me.

Current Code :

```
var username = "123456";
var password = "234567";

angular.module('abcControllers', [])
    .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
                $scope.abc.data = {name: username,email: username+"@test.com",login:username,password :password};
    });



    <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate ng-init="advanced = false">
              <div class="form-group {{ (((!form.name.$pristine || form.$submitted) && !form.name.$valid) ? 'has-error': '') }}">
                <label class="control-label" for="login-name">{{ 'NAME' | translate}}</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="login-name" placeholder="{{ 'YOUR_NAME' | translate}}" required="" ng-model="abc.data.name" autofocus>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group {{ (((!form.email.$pristine || form.$submitted) && !form.email.$valid) ? 'has-error': '') }}">
                <label class="control-label" for="login-email">{{ 'EMAIL' | translate }}</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="login-email" placeholder="{{ 'YOUR_EMAIL' | translate}}" required="" ng-model="abc.data.email" ng-model-options="{debounce: 250}">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group" ng-hide="!advanced">
                  <label class="control-label" for="login-user">{{ 'USER' | translate}}</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login-user" placeholder="{{ 'USER' | translate}}" ng-model="abc.data.login">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" ng-hide="!advanced">
                <label class="control-label" for="login-password">{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate}}</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login-password" placeholder="{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate}}" ng-model="abc.data.password">
              </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please insert values in the controller rather than outside it:

```
angular.module('abcControllers', [])
.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
             var username = "123456";
             var password = "234567";
             $scope.abc.data = {name: username,email: username+"@test.com",login:username,password :password};
});
```

Also,make sure that your controller is bind with the html.

Comment: Thanks for reply,But as i see only variable inside of angular block.
no any other diffference am i right ?

Comment: Okay,I have similar question like i want to set variable from url in which i can get variables value as a GET and once value get then want to execute click event

Comment: Then you have to call http call which return json object according to your need and then simple assign that value to this varibles.

Answer (score 0):

Try making this change

```
    $scope.abc = {}; 
    $scope.abc.data = {name:username,   //data of undefined solved
        email:username+"@test.com",
        login:username,
        password :password};
```